# How to show data when scroll page to bottom with append();

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How to show data when scroll page to bottom with `append();` ?

first , when you load page index.php it's will show 88888 and more `br tag`

when you scroll page to bottom , i want to show 88888 and more `br tag` with append(); function , how can i do that ?

index.php

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
$("#fid").submit(f1());
</script>


<form method="post" id="fid" action="Javascript:void(0);" >
    <input type='hidden' id='numbers' name='numbers' value='88888'/>
</form>
<div id="demoajax">

<script>
function f1(){
    $('#demoajax').hide();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'demo.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#fid').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $('#demoajax').show();
            $('#demoajax').html(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
}
// on load page call function code //
$(document).ready(f1());
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){       
       var height = $('#demoajax').height();
       var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();       
        if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())){           
            $('#demoajax').hide();
            $('#protect_form_between_ajax_process').show();
            $('#loading').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'demo.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#fid').serialize(),
                success: function(data){
           $('#demoajax').append(data);
                    }
                });
            return false;
    }
    return false;   
    });
}); 
</script>
```

demo.php

```
<?PHP
echo $_POST[numbers];
?>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: like an infinite scroll? why so many br tags, is that just to create space in this example?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and it must work out

Try this condition

```
 ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= ( $(document).height()  - 200)) //  This will ensure that ajax call is send when there is 200px area left for user to scroll
```

or

```
 $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == ( $(document).outerHeight(true)) // This will give the exact height
```